# Java VM - DCEVM updates for JDK 8

Tags: java, jvm

I am using Oracle HotSpot JVM 1.8 u121.

Although it says that the the light distro is available here

http://dcevm.github.io/

It doesn't look like it works with JDK 1.8. I tried to install it and it gives me the following error:

```
Error: missing `decvm' JVM at `C:\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\decvm\jvm.dll'.
Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
```

My JDK is fully functional, so nothing is wrong here. Does anyone know if DCEVM is supposed to work with JDK 8 at all?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I got it working working with Oracle's JDK 1.8, and had a similar issue. For me, I needed to re-run the DCEVM installer jar ensure that 'Replaced by DCDEVM?' and also 'Installed altjvm?' are both Yes. After that it worked.